# Where have all my labels gone? Topbraid owl to SHACL conversion

Tags: rdfs, linked-data, shacl, skos, topbraid-composer

I'm trying to convert my ontology, from OWL to SHACL. However, the SKOS labels, preflabels, comments etc. are not being converted. At least, they don't come back in the ttl file that is generated. Right now, I load my original TTL file into topbraid, and use Model -> Convert OWL/RDFS To SHACL... -> standard settings . This works great: All of my object properties, data properties, cardinalities etc. are neatly converted, however, everything that is not SHACL is completely ommited from the resulting TTL file, including my preflabels and comments.

What am I doing wrong: Or better: How do I convert everything to SHACL, but keep the SKOS things in there?

Thank you for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OWL to SHACL importer only produces the SHACL-specific triples. The rest of the class definition can remain in the OWL file, and typically the generated SHACL file will owl:import the original OWL file. As a result, if anyone opens the SHACL file, the definitions from the OWL file will also still be there.

Comment: Thank you, this is a clear answer. I think I was hoping for a method which combines both the shacl file and the owl file into one ttl file. The import works, but requires you to open the files in something like topbraid. I would also ilke to be open the file in a text edior like notepad ++ and have the SKOS andRDFS things alongside the SHACL.